# How to find string in HTML response

Tags: perl, lwp

I have written a script to login to a web page and print the response. Now I want to find a string in the HTML response, but I don't know how.

My current code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;


my $clientIP = "129.168.1.50:80";
my $clientURL = "http://" . $clientIP . "/conf";

## User Agent (UA)
my $ua=LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);

$ua->credentials($clientIP, 'Secure Area', 'user', 'pa$$word');

my $page = $ua->get($clientURL);
my $body = $page->content();
print $body;
```

Current print output from `$body`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>configuration</title>
</head>

<body>
        <h1>Client</h1>
        <p>
                Version
                2.16.4.9</p>
        <a href="settings">Settings</a>
        <br>
        <a href="updateskin">Update skin</a>
        <br>
        <a href="updatesettings">Update settings</a>
        <br>
        <p>Software Solutions</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I find the version string and number in the response and write it to a variable?

The goal of the script is to get the version number and write it to a file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your help. The regular expression is the simplest solution.

```
# Remove all wordwraps
while($body=~s/[\n\r\l]//){} 
my $ver='unknown'; # Default version
if($body=~/version\s*([0-9\.]+)/i){$ver=$1;}
print "\n" . $ver . "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](http://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder) which will process the HTML for you and allow you to navigate the resulting structure

The code would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $client_ip  = '129.168.1.50:80';
my $client_url = "http://$client_ip/conf";

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_url($client_url);

my $version;

for my $p ( $tree->look_down(_tag => 'p') ) {
    my $text =  $p->as_trimmed_text;
    if ( $text =~ / version /ix ) {
        $version = $text;
        last;
    }
}

print $version, "\n";
```

Comment: That's what I meant with screen scraping. :)

Comment: @simbabque: I prefer *Mojolicious* for this sort of job, but somehow it's hard to persuade people to use it. `HTML::TreeBuilder` is getting a little long in the tooth nowadays

Comment: I would have suggested _Web::Scraper_. I like that a lot for simple scraping. _WWW::Mechanize_ would have worked here, too. I'm not the biggest Mojo fan though their HTML parser is really strong. I think I don't like their roll-your-own attitude.

Comment: @simbabqe: Instead of "would have suggested", post a Web::Scraper answer. If you have a different way to do it, add it to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Mojo](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent) example. There are a few differences between LWP::UserAgent and [Mojo::UserAgent](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent) that make it worth it for me. First, the `get` returns a transaction that knows about the request and the response. That may not be important here, but I find I often want it. Next, I can immediately get a DOM object and call `find` on it with CSS selectors, such as `h1 > p` which means "the p after h1". From that I get a collection which I can call `map` on. In this case, I tell `map` to call the `text` method on each item from the collection of found thingys:

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $url = "http://$user:$password\@$clientIP/conf";

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $tx   = $ua->get($url);

my( $version ) = $tx->res->dom->find( 'h1 > p' )->map( 'text' );
```

The last thing I like is that Mojolicious is self-contained. I don't have to install multiple things and risk something outside of Mojo breaking part of the installation process.

Comment: Perhaps `my $version = $tx->res->dom->find( 'h1 > p' )->[0]->text`? There's no need to extract the text content of all the elements found.